# Mock reference in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i am doing unit testing of entity framework with repository pattern. I just try to mock a repository class in my test project

```
private Mock<IStudentRepository> repositoryMock;
```

and i am using the namespace

```
 Using Moq;    // is that correct????????
```

but the assembly reference/directive is missing error shows, so i try to add references, but i cant understand which is assembly reference/directive of Moq. Can anybody please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to define the "using" in lowercase.

Make sure that you have referenced the Moq library in your project. You could use NuGet to get it:

```
Install-Package Moq
```